# Equivalent of simple storage API for restartless firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Is there an equivalent to [this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) or a way to call it from a restartless extension? I need to store a few strings between browser sessions.

I have found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage) but it seems too complicated for simple string storage. Does the SS API use the same thing behind the scene?

Comment: The simple-storage api should work just fine when developing restartless addons with the addon-sdk. Have you tried the examples? Do they fail or give you any error?

Comment: That's the point. I'm not using addon-sdk. I'm using native code from `bootstrap.js` since I work with a lot of external dll functions.

Comment: I'll try to move the current extension to the addon-sdk soon but I need a fix until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import any SDK module into normal restartless extensions this way:

```
const { devtools } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {});
const { require } = devtools;

let ss = require('sdk/simple-storage');
```

Comment: Not entirely sure this is a good idea... This will give you a `simple-storage` instance that is shared between `devtools` and any other add-on that uses this hack. So if two different add-ons use this *shared* `devtools` instance with the same key, things will go **boom**. Better create a proper SDK loader yourself.

Comment: Working on it as we speak. I just needed a temporary fix in the meantime. The add-on is used as a proof of concept right now, it's going live only after a lot of work :)

Comment: Importing SDK simple-storage into a normal restartless extensions will fail since simple-storage uses extension ID in `storeFile.append(jpSelf.id);` (line 192) which is not available.

Answer (score 3):

The `simple-storage`/`localStorage` APIs suck because of synchronous file I/O.
There are alternatives such as `IndexedDB` which [can be used from `chrome`/add-on code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB_in_chrome) quite easily.

You can also use `localStorage` in your add-on (no need to use the SDK `simple-storage` API), but should not use `window.localStorage` in overlays because that would be shared between add-ons, and cannot use `window.localStorage` in `bootstrap.js` and/or js code modules because there simply is no `window`. But you can construct a storage object yourself.

```
function getStorage(uri) {
  if (!(uri instanceof Ci.nsIURI)) {
    uri = Services.io.newURI(uri, null, null);
  }
  let principal = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"].
    getService(Ci.nsIScriptSecurityManager).
    getNoAppCodebasePrincipal(uri);
  let dsm = Cc["@mozilla.org/dom/localStorage-manager;1"].
    getService(Ci.nsIDOMStorageManager);
  return dsm.createStorage(principal, "");
}

var s1 = getStorage("chrome://my-addon/content/whatever.xul"); // does not actually have to point to a resource.
```

The usual limitations of `localStorage` apply (quotas and such).

BTW: The code also lets you access the `localStorage` of websites, e.g. `getStorage("http://stackoverflow.com/");`.

Comment: `dsm.createStorage(principal, "")` did not work for me until I specified `null` as a first parameter `dsm.createStorage(null,principal, "")`. Maybe would be useful... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Session store API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Session_store_API) ([nsISessionStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISessionStore)):

```
const ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1"].getService(Ci.nsISessionStore);
ss.setGlobalValue("my-extension-few-strings", "blah blah blah");
const fewStrings = ss.getGlobalValue("my-extension-few-strings");
// fewStrings === "blah blah blah";
ss.deleteGlobalValue("my-extension-few-strings");
```

Session store is shared across all extensions, so choose unique names for stored values (e.g. prepend all key names with your extension name). And unlike simple-storage and localStorage it's not limited in size.

p.s. `setGlobalValue`, `getGlobalValue`, `deleteGlobalValue` are not documented anywhere.